# Unable to send file from ftp to another ftp

Tags: php, ftp, server, file-transfer

I have searched a lot for the answer and found some results but none of one is working for me. I want to transfer zip file from one server to another server using ftp functions. File went transferred but without data. Here is my code as follows:

```
<?php

$file = 'LICENSE.zip';
$fp = 'LICENSE.zip';


$ftp_server = "ftpserver name";
$ftp_user_name = "ftp username";
$ftp_user_pass = "ftp password"; 

// set up basic connection

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);


$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// login with username and password

// upload a file
ftp_chdir($conn_id,'/dev');

if (ftp_put($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_BINARY)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";

 } else {
  echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection

 ftp_close($conn_id);

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Even I am unable to transfer a simple `.php` or `.txt` file with their data. In this case only files without data is moving.

Comment: Please check file / directory permission on target ftp.

Comment: If target ftp able to create the file then what can be reason for data writing on the file.

Comment: Your code only uploads a file. Where is the download part from the other server? The steps should be: 1. download the remote ftp file in a local temporary location; 2. upload the file to the second server by ftp

Comment: So what I need to put in my code now @machineaddict